Python: Concurrent execution of drission chromiumpage
I have created one api that calls the function whose task is to extract web content from url that has been shared as a parameter.
I am facing a problem when my api is getting multiple request, the chromium page instance that is getting invoked from drission is only once, and my urls are getting overridden to the same browser.
I also tried auto_port() that is invoking multiple instances but again while fetching the contents, my data is getting messed up.
Like url is from xyz.com and content is from abc.com while url is from abc.com and content is from pqr.com
Is there any way to handle it?
I used multithreading and  multiprocessing both, none of them are working for me.
Thanks
I tried multithreading, multiprocessing and asyncio

you need one thread per driver/browser pair.  (so separate driver references/objects for each instantiated driver)

Please read [ask], especially the part about [mcve] (MCVE). Take the code you are using, reduce it to an MCVE, and then post that code as text, properly indented and formatted. Post the full error message as text, properly formatted, and indicate on which line the error is occurring.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
